# What is Lucius Mafoy's occupation?

Tags: harry-potter

What does Lucius Malfoy do for work? I know they have a lot of gold, so how did the family obtain it? Was it inherited just like the Potter family? He was a school governor, but was that his only job? Not sure if school governors actually get paid. I don't think he actually worked at the ministry, from what it says in the novels he just stopped in from time to time to give good to various organizations.

Harry Potter Order of the Phoenix 
Chapter Educational Decreee Number 24 quoting Draco Malfoy

> 'Yeah, Umbridge gave the Slytherin Quidditch team permission to continue playing straightaway, I went to ask her first thing this morning. Well, it was pretty much automatic, I mean, she knows my father really well, he's always popping in and out of the Ministry . . . it'll be interesting to see whether Gryffindor are allowed to keep playing, won't it?'

Does anyone know what Lucius Mafoy's job was and how be has so much money?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's meant to be the magical equivalent of some unspecified level of nobility.  If so, then we would not expect him to work for a living.

Comment: "Senior Rich White Dude"

Comment: I saw a rather well-researched essay with a theory that he wasn't as wealthy as he appeared, and that maintaining the appearance of wealth, for leverage for political shenanegins, was a great deal of effort.  The essay focusing on him is [here](https://pharnabazus.livejournal.com/2450.html#cutid1), the essay series begins [here](https://pharnabazus.livejournal.com/715.html)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the Malfoys don't work.  From the [page describing their family](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-malfoy-family) at Pottermore:

> Independently wealthy, with no need to work for a living, they have generally preferred the role of power behind the throne, happy for others to do the donkey work and to take the responsibility for failure.